# Ruby - nils appearing in array

Tags: ruby, arrays, null

I was helping a friend out with a ruby assignment, and I ran into some peculiar behavior. We've refactored it to use a Hash and increment the counts directly through that, so this code is obsolete, but for my own sanity, I need to know why nil values show up in the packets array. The strangest thing is that it doesn't always happen, it only happens on some executions.

I should note that the purpose of the code is essentially to tally the number of times in a row that the random value is below p.

```
count = 0
p = 0.1
packets = []
counts = []

10000.times do
  if rand.round(1) <= p
    count += 1
  elsif count > 0
    packets << count
    count = 0
  end
end

packets.each do |train|
  counts[train] = counts.fetch(train, 0) + train
end

counts.each_with_index do |value, index|
  puts "Train Length: #{index} Count: #{value}"
end
```

The packets array should only ever contain numerical values, but it winds up with multiple nil's. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you *certain* that your `packets` array is getting `nil`s? There's basically no way that could happen with the code you posted. Dump out the `packets` array to be sure.

*However*, I do observe that the code sometimes fails with the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
    from (irb):16:in `block in irb_binding'
    from (irb):15:in `each'
    from (irb):15
    from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

from the line

```
counts[train] = counts.fetch(train, 0) + train
```

This error means that `counts.fetch(train, 0)` was `nil` (if `train` was `nil`, you'd get a coercion error instead). This can happen if, for example, you set `counts[3]` before `counts[2]` is set, and later access `counts[2]` (because Ruby will fill the array elements you "skipped over" with `nil`s).

If you are actually getting `nil`s in `packets`, then you may have demons in your Ruby.

Comment: Yes, that was the cause. The code was setting later indices of `counts` before the earlier ones, which was resulting in populating the array with nil's before it.